# Misuse of custom close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was going through the close review queue, I saw the question 
[Satellite is brought to the earth’s surface, it hits the earth with a velocity of 4 km/s - Determine the work done by friction [on hold]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294480/satellite-is-brought-to-the-earth-s-surface-it-hits-the-earth-with-a-velocity-o) and voted to close as homework. However, before doing so, I saw the close reason "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because '*Ive subtracted the values I got, but it says the answer is wrong*'".

How is this an actual close reason? Would the person who posted that close reason explain their thinking, and/or someone explain if this type of more vague close reason is okay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That person was, as you can see in the comments below the question, Alfred Centauri. He was apparently quoting a line from one of the comments that must have, on its own, made the entire post seem close-worthy. I'd not call it a very professional thing to have done and would agree that closing it as homework would be the proper thing to do. My opinion would be that this type of thing is not really okay because it does not actually provide a non-listed but viable close reason, which is the whole point of the custom option. The OP has no feedback about why their post was not acceptable. And there existed another close reason that adequately covered the issue.

So no, this isn't really good practice. At least, not according to Jim

Comment: You don't know how bad I want to edit in [this link to your last three words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/According_to_Jim)

Comment: @KyleKanos I know. I'm also tempted to poorly construct a reference to The World According to Garp.

Comment: Isn't Jim's family resembling yours @kyle?

Comment: @mafia: if you mean the TV show, I only recall Jim having 3 kids, though the wiki link says he has 5 in the end.